# Ubuntu 14.04 Terminal on virtualbox maintenance

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-10

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 terminal server on VirtualBox 5.0.12 (which is installed on Windows 10). I ran out of disk space apparently (although I have 10 GB space) so I read and I understood that I need to do some maintenance to my system regularly.

Could someone please let me know how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are several things, that you can try:

1. Reboot (-> everytime you reboot, the /tmp directory gets cleaned).
2. Try to track down where your system consumed the most space. You can do it by issuing a `du -h --max-depth=1 /`. You will get a list of your root-fs directories along with the used disk space. If you spot, e.g. that in /home there is 7G stuff, call the same du command but for /home: `du -h --max-depth=1 /home`. Finally you will find out, where the most space gets lost.
3. If you don't want to create a new VM with more disk space, you can add a new virtual harddisk with more space and mount it to a directory that is consuming a lot of space. Normally /home or /opt would be a candidate, but it depends completely on your system and what you're doing with it. If you wan't to do that, try this tutorial here: https://howtobi.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/adding-a-additional-hard-disk-in%C2%A0virtualbox/